# Fancybox - Integrating jQuery Ui Accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, fancybox, accordion

I'm currently using Fancybox and would like to add the ability to toggle open or close the text caption under the image using the jQuery UI accordion. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time getting jQuery UI accordion to work. I tested an accordion on the page (outside of Fancybox) and it worked fine.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'titlePosition' : 'outside',
});

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true
});

});
</script>


<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="images/example.jpg" title="<div id='accordion'><h3><a href='#'>Example</a></h3><div><p>text here</p></div></div>" ><img src="images/example.jpg" alt="Portraits"></a>
```

Any guidance would be really appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you just trying to open a comment under an image? Accordion seems overkill (and just plain wrong if Im honest...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to toggle the title inside fancybox without using any other plugin?

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
 'titlePosition' : 'over',
 'onComplete' : function() {
  $("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
   $("#fancybox-title").show();
  }, function() {
   $("#fancybox-title").hide();
  }); // hover
 } // onComplete
}); // fancybox
```

Check demo at http://fancybox.net/blog No. 3

You could even add some animation tweaking the `onComplete` option like

```
'onComplete' : function() {
 $("#fancybox-title").hide();
 $("#fancybox-wrap").hover(function() {
  $("#fancybox-title").stop(true,true).slideDown(200);
 }, function() {
  $("#fancybox-title").stop(true,true).slideUp(200);
 }); // hover
} // onComplete
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this fiddle

[image with slideToggle description](http://jsfiddle.net/ft3Ge/)